# How to generate with Hive Adapter files in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I use hive to save my model, I assign values to my class via api, I need to be able to assign values via api and have a class that generated hive do I need to make 2 separate classes? One for assigning values from api with the fromJson method and one for my hive? Are there any other ways to solve this problem?

```
Here is my class 

class ProductFilterModel {
  ProductFilterModel({
    required this.value,
    required this.name,
    required this.initialValue,
    required this.childData,
  });

  var value;
  String? name;
  var initialValue;
  late final  List<ChildData> childData;

  ProductFilterModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    value = json['value'];
    name = json['name'];
    initialValue = json['initial_value'];
    childData = List.from(json['data'])
        .map((e) => ChildData.fromJson(e))
        .toList();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['value'] = value;
    data['name'] = name;
    data['initial_value'] = initialValue;
    data['data'] = childData.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList();
    return data;
  }
}

class ChildData {
  ChildData({
    required this.value,
    required this.text,
  });
  late final value;
  late final String text;

  ChildData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    value = json['value'];
    text = json['text'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['value'] = value;
    data['text'] = text;
    return data;
  }
}

// example of use
Future<ProductFilterModel> getType() async {
    var url = '';
    final response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(url),
        headers: Constants.headers()
    );
    final body = jsonDecode(response.body);
    final data = ProductFilterModel.fromJson(body['data']);
    return data;
  }
```

how can i generate this model with hive?